# 2checkout.com payment method integration in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Can any one help me with 2checkout.com payment method integration in PHP step wise? I have written a form as it is described in documentation of 2checkout.com site for inline process. After submitting the form it shows that the payment is successful but I didn't receive any IPN result in my function. So hence it is proved that payment is not done.

I will be grateful if anyone helps me with this. sample code is listed below. What I have to do next after that to get exact response from 2checkout so that I can understand the payment has been successful.

```
<form id="2checkout" action='https://sandbox.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase' method='post'>
  <input type='hidden' name='sid' value='111111111' />
  <input type='hidden' name='mode' value='2CO' />
  <input type='hidden' name='li_0_type' value='product' />
  <input type='hidden' name='li_0_name' value='test title' />
  <input type='hidden' name='li_0_price' value='212.00' />
  <input type='hidden' name='x_receipt_link_url' value='http://myserver.com/ipn_twocheckout' /> 
  <input type='hidden' name='card_holder_name' value='Joe Flagster' />
  <input type='hidden' name='street_address' value='123 Main Street' />
  <input type='hidden' name='street_address2' value='Suite 200' />
  <input type='hidden' name='city' value='Townsville' />
  <input type='hidden' name='state' value='Ohio' />
  <input type='hidden' name='zip' value='43206' />
  <input type='hidden' name='country' value='USA' />
  <input type='hidden' name='email' value='mysample@gmail.com' />
  <input type='hidden' name='phone' value='614-921-2450' />

</form> 
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('2checkout').submit();</script>
<script src="https://www.2checkout.com/static/checkout/javascript/direct.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not somewhere to ask someone to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to verify that a payment was successful is to simply validate it on the return, here's an example of a return validation, assuming that you are returning to this page after the purchase is complete at 2Checkout:

```
<?php
$hashSecretWord = 'tango'; //2Checkout Secret Word
$hashSid = 111111111; //2Checkout account number
$hashTotal = '212.00'; //Sale total to validate against
$hashOrder = $_REQUEST['order_number']; //2Checkout Order Number
$StringToHash = strtoupper(md5($hashSecretWord . $hashSid . $hashOrder . $hashTotal));

if ($StringToHash != $_REQUEST['key']) {
    $result = 'Fail - Hash Mismatch'; 
    } else { 
    $result = 'Success - Hash Matched';
}

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

simple problem:

your submitting payment in sandbox mode. 
(https://sandbox.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase)

in this case "x_receipt_link_url" parameter will not work.
(it will only work for live account).

to test the response in your project. 
login to your sandbox account. then navigate to 
(please find the below attachments for clear idea)
Account tab=>site management tab.
then select the radio button Header Redirect.
then
Enter the approved url and affiliate url as : http://myserver.com/ipn_twocheckout (your site url to receive success callback and handling).

then save changes.

i hope this answer will help you.
[image]
[image]